# How to avoid re-render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, accordion

I am making a simple accordion which has text editor inside it.

If we click expand text then the text editor gets opened and if we enter some text inside the editor and click shrink, then the accordion gets closed.

Again if click on the expand text of accordion where we made the changes, then the text already entered is missing inside it.

I can understand that this re render every time we click on the expand text. Also this code,

```
<Text>  {toggleValue === index && item.content && <EditorContainer />} </Text>
```

check for the item clicked then it gets opened so re render happens here and hence I am losing the entered text.

**Complete working example:**

> **https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-dcqbo**

Could you please kindly help me to retain the value entered inside the text editor despite of the clicks over the text Expand/Shrink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the editor's state into a persistent parent component. Since the `NormalAccordion` encompasses all editors, and you want persistent state just *one* editor, use another component, so that the state doesn't get lost when the editor unmounts, then pass it down for the editor to use:

```
const OuterEditorContainer = ({ toggleValue, setToggleValue, item, index }) => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

  const toggleHandler = (index) => {
    index === toggleValue ? setToggleValue(-1) : setToggleValue(index);
  };
  return (
    <Accordion>
      <Heading>
        <div
          style={{ padding: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
          className="heading"
          onClick={() => toggleHandler(index)}
        >
          {toggleValue !== index ? `Expand` : `Shrink`}
        </div>
      </Heading>
      <Text>
        {toggleValue === index && item.content && (
          <EditorContainer {...{ editorState, setEditorState }} />
        )}
      </Text>
    </Accordion>
  );
};
const NormalAccordion = () => {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(-1);
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {accordionData.map((item, index) => (
        <OuterEditorContainer
          {...{ toggleValue, setToggleValue, item, index }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// text_editor.js
export default ({ editorState, setEditorState }) => (
  <div className="editor">
    <Editor
      editorState={editorState}
      onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
      toolbar={{
        inline: { inDropdown: true },
        list: { inDropdown: true },
        textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
        link: { inDropdown: true },
        history: { inDropdown: true }
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

You could also put the state into the `text_editor` itself, and always render that container, but only conditionally render the `<Editor`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Could you please provide working sandbox by forking mine in the question?

Comment: The changes in the answer are really all you need, but if you need a link too: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-mi7s0?file=/src/Accordion.js

Comment: Once again thanks for providing the link.. But here if I enter a text inside any of the editor and if I close that accordion and if I open any other accordion, then the previously entered text is present inside other accordion which is irrelevant.. Could you please kindly check that?

Comment: The entered text inside editor is related to that specific accordion alone.. Now the change in any of the text editor gets reflected in all other text editor..

Comment: Oh, you have a `.map`, so that would've had them all share the same state. Use a different container for each editor, and put the persistent state for each into that instead.

Comment: Once again thanks.. What should I need to do if I want to display the content before text editor? Like ```This is a first content```, ```This is a second content```, ```This is a third content``` respectively before text editor.

Comment: Have the `OuterEditorContainer` render the `accordionData` item it received from props?

Comment: Could you please help me on this query https://stackoverflow.com/q/63725657/13270726 where I got stuck for long time and this also related to re render issue only ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the entered text and pass it as props from the parent component to EditorContainer.

Right now everytime you render it (e.g. when we click expand)
It looks like you set an empty state.

Something like:

**EditorContainer**

```
  editorState: this.props.editorState || EditorState.createEmpty()

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    // console.log(editorState)
    this.props.setEditorState(editorState);
  };
```

And in **Accordion**:

```
{toggleValue === index && 
 item.content && 
<EditorContainer 
editorState={this.state.editorState[index]} 
setEditorState={newText => this.setState({...this.state, newText}) />}
```

Didn't try to execute it, but I think that's the way to achieve it.
Ps: Class components are almost not used anymore. Try to use function components and learn about [useState](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook, looks so much cleaner in my opinion