# Component re-render issue [Snippet Attached]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a resume builder application and the whole structure was almost done.

**Complete working codesandbox:**

[image: Edit next-dynamic-testing-issue (forked)]

Here I have made components into stepper for each section,

**index.js**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Stepper
          steps={sections}
          activeStep={currentPage}
          activeColor="red"
          defaultBarColor="red"
          completeColor="green"
          completeBarColor="green"
        />

        {currentPage === 1 && (
          <>
            <BasicDetails />
            <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
          </>
        )}

        {currentPage === 2 && (
          <>
            <EmploymentDetails />
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <button onClick={prev}>Back</button>
              <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}

        {currentPage === 3 && (
          <>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}</pre>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <button onClick={prev}>Back</button>
              <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </form>
```

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

-> In `Step 1` Enter `First Name`, `Last Name`, and `Profile Summary`

-> Click on `Next` button to move to next step.

-> Then click the back button to move backward to `Step 1` (Currently in `Step 2`)

-> Here the values in `First Name`, `Last Name` are there but the **value entered in text editor alone gets lost**

Please refer the below image with text editor value entered for better understanding of the problem I am facing..

Text editor value alone gets lost if we switch `forth/back` the steps. But the entered value is stored in the form Context and not rendered in the Text Editor box.

[image]

***Note:***

Text editor is made as a component and it was used in `Step 1` (For profile summary) and also in `Step 2` (For employment description) and in both cases switching between steps, the value entered inside the text editor gets lost.

***Analysis:***

Based on my understanding, this happens because on navigating to other steps, the component get re-rendered and the `EditorContainer` component gets called and in `text_editor.js` it was given

```
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
};
```

So it was created as empty.

So how can I control the component from getting re-rendered so that the data entered in text editor won't get lost.

Kindly please help me to retain the values entered inside the text editor. Big thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because we're only saving our `EditorContainer` value to our `Context`, but we're not using it when we rerender the `EditorContainer` component.

---

The fix would be to pass the saved `value` as prop to our `EditorContainer` component.

Then before we render the `EditorContainer`, we'll convert that `value` to `EditorState` which can be done using [`convertFromHTML`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#convertfromhtml) function, and set that as our `editorState` state.

**Step 1: Pass `value` prop to `EditorContainer`**

```js
// basic_details.js
<EditorContainer
 name="profileSummary"
  value={basicDetails.profileSummary}
  onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
/>

// employment_details.js
<EditorContainer
  name="description"
  value={inputField.description}
  onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(index, event)}
/>
```

**Step 2: Convert the `value` prop to `EditorState`**

```js
// text_editor.js
...

componentDidMount() {
  // https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#convertfromhtml

  const { value } = this.props;
  const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(value);
  const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
  );

  const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(state);
  this.setState({ editorState });
}
```

That's it! Check the demo below.

**Edit** Fix demo to check `value` if is string.

[image: Edit next-dynamic-testing-issue (forked)]

Comment: Great work.. I appoligize for accepting answer in late.. It works perfectly the way needed..

Comment: It's okay, no problem @Undefined. :)

Comment: Can you tell me the steps on how should I include the codesandbox link as like you did it in every solution? I am keen on knowing that.. Its looking good..

Comment: On the right top of the codesandox, click the `Share` blue button -> `Embed` -> `Other Sharing Options` -> `Copy the Markdown` -> paste that on your post.

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question with the steps you have mentioned.. Again thanks for your help..

Comment: Bro sorry question for you again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843604/how-to-make-a-step-active

Comment: Bro can you help me here please https://stackoverflow.com/q/64121098/13270726

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. This is basically a design approach issue: For a scenario like yours, you need to design your component this way:
[image]

let's analyze the picture:

**MAIN COMPONENT:**

This is the component that should hold the state for the entire form-filling process. STE1-4 Are just views that allows you to input data that must all be updated in the main component. So This means, you must have state in main component and pass the state properties and `props`, including their update/setter methods.

**STEP COMPONENT**
*This applies for all Step Components.*
These components should do nothing except display the form step using state values received via `props` and update state by using setter methods, which are also received via `props`.

---

Conclusion:

Put your state in your main component, each step component should only display the form and update the main state. This means that by the time each step component is re-rendered, it will receive values updated in the main component. And you will achieve that via `props`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation in detail.. Could you kindly please provide the solution by forking the above given codesandbox in question.. I am new in react js and javascript and hence seeking a example way of solution.. Kindly provide working codesandbox as a solution and thanks once again..

Comment: Okay, I'll fork your CodesAndBox now quickly.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just forked your code and tested it. It seems to be working fine. After filling in values, and then click next... and then back, those values are still there because I can see you used Context. Which is another approach.

Comment: No try once again.. I have explained in question clearly that first name and last name value is there if we are coming back but the text editor value alone gets lost.. There are totally 3 fields in the ```Step 1``` .. Please fill all the 3 fields (including text editor ) and click ```Next``` button then you will be redirected to ```Step 2``` then click ```Back``` button, now in ```Step 1``` only first two input fields value is there but the 3rd input which is a text editor value gets lost and it is empty.. But in form context the value is there whereas in UI , that value not get binded..

Comment: In form JSON, the entered value was there but if we switch between the steps then already entered text editor (Profile Summary) value not got binded..

Comment: Hope you understand the problem clearly.. The above given codesandbox really has a problem in binding of value to the text editor while switching between the steps.. Kindly please go through once again and provide working solution please..

Comment: I have also attached image to my question for explaining better about the problem I am facing.. Kindly please help..

Comment: Oh Ok. I see what you mean. Let me check again.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple - you need to store editors state in your parent component. Try to use BasicDetails state for this.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get your point.. Can you provide solution by forking the above given codesandbox?